Can I retrieve a non-default test version via the XrayExportBuilder object in the Xray/Jenkins Integration plugin?
My work place recently upgraded to Xray Enterprise. We were specifically interested in trying to leverage Xray Test Versioning in our automation testing.

We hoped that, after creating new test versions for existing tests, we would be able to run those new test versions in our automation environments BEFORE setting the new test versions as the ‘default’ version. This would allow us to greatly facilitate the updating/transition of tests as a result of our product updates.
Unfortunately, it appears as if that might not currently be possible. We use a plugin to integrate with Jenkins. We use the XrayExportBuilder object to pull feature files from Xray. The Documentation for the XrayExportBuilder object: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+Jenkins shows that the ‘issues’ Parameter has no optional ‘version’ argument. We can see from trial and error, this object appears to always return the ‘default’ test version of the ticket ID(s) provided to it.
Is there a way to get the above mentioned plugin/XrayExportBuilder object to return a non-default version of a test ticket?
To be clear, I’m talking about test versions, NOT the general versions on JIRA issues.

A small clarification: are you sing Xray on Jira Cloud or Xray on Jira Datacenter?

Independently on wether you're using Xray on Jira Datacenter or Xray on Jira Cloud, in this case the answer is the same.
To my knowledge, the Jenkins plugin uses the public Xray REST APIs (cloud REST API, DC REST API).
As of today, there's no way to specify the test version neither on the Jenkins nor on the Cucumber export REST API endpoint.
You can ask for a new feature by reaching out Xray's Support team.
Nevertheless, I foresee a challenge: test versions are not global.. they are defined on a per Test basis. Therefore, you don't have a version "v2" (for example), that you can say that applies to a bunch of Tests. That concept doesn't exist in Xray, so exporting "v2" of a bunch of Tests is not applicable. Of course, you could have versions with the same naming on different Tests, but that would be more a convention within the team that can easily break; that could be an acceptable risk though.

Update: I was able to get a suggestion ticket created for this via Xray support!
https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAYCLOUD-7650
